# Configure Tomcat8 behind Apache with HTTPS

Tags: https, apache2, tomcat8, proxypass

I have Tomcat 8 installed in my server in port 8080 that I am exposing with a secured Apache (using Proxy Pass).

Here is my Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass           /odata/    http://172.31.36.251:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse    /odata/    http://172.31.36.251:8080/

    <Proxy *>
        allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Scheme https
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the Tomcat server.xml configuration

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="8443" 
            address="172.31.36.251" 
            proxyName="myserver.com" 
            scheme="https" proxyPort="443"  />
```

All works well until here. If I call my application:
https://myserver.com/odata/D3a1593adae89/odata.svc/

I get:

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="https://myserver.com:443/D3a1593adae89/odata.svc/">
<workspace>
<atom:title>Default</atom:title>
<collection href="Maintables">
<atom:title>Maintables</atom:title>
</collection>
</workspace>
</service>
```

**The problem:**  If you see the attribute **xml:base** in the result, Tomcat decorates the address with the port and I really don't know how to remove it. Also the address is wrong: It should be https://myserver.com:443/**odata**/D3a1593adae89/odata.svc/  . I been looking around and trying things like setting *proxyPort* to blank but nothing. I think this is related to broken links when using a reverse proxy as described at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/TomcatModProxyHTML . I tried some rewrites like:

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://172.31.33.105:8080 /odata
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^/odata$ https://myserver.com/odata/ [R,L]
```

But I just cannot make it work. The xml:base should be https://myserver.com/odata/D3a1593adae89/odata.svc/

Any idea is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the port thing, as you use `ProxyPreserveHost On` and you set `X-Forwarded-*` headers, you can use the `RemoteIpValve`:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" />
```

The connector will be simply:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="443" 
            address="172.31.33.105" 
             />
```

The valve detect the `proto` and will assume the connection is secured with the default port number (`https://xxxxx/yyy`).

For the location, you should deploy your application in the `odata` context so that you can use

```
    ProxyPass           /odata    http://172.31.33.105:8080/odata
```

modifying the context on the proxy pass (from /odata/ to /) is somehow tricky as you would need to filter all text coming from your backend server to fix some url path. It can be really painful ( should I replace all "/xxx" with "/odata/xxx" ? )

Comment: OK. Where do I add the <Valve

Comment: it is a standard config, so in the `conf/server.xml` file

Comment: 172.31.36.251


With:

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" />
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" address="172.31.36.251"/>
I get:
Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

Look that we changed to the server to 172.31.36.251

Comment: I removed the address="172.31.36.251" because tomcat runs in Docker. That removed the error but I got the same behavior

Comment: I just saw you set `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Scheme https`   the more "official" header is    `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https`.  It is the on set on protocolHeader of the valve.  ( X-Forwarded-* are not official but they was/are pretty comon )

Comment: More than a year later I managed to do it with "RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https" in apache and just the RemoteIpValve as you indicated. Changing the connector was not needed. Thanks a lot